# Example of a set not closed under multiplication

Tags: binary-operations

It might be a stupid question, but can you give me some example of multiplication not being closed in some set?

I could find a case in "addition"(e.g., a set of odd numbers is not closed under addition) but am struggling to find an example for multiplication.

Comment: For instance, a set of imaginary numbers?

Comment: The set of all real numbers between $-2$ and $2$

Comment: I also found that the irrational numbers are not closed too..

Comment: The singleton set containing 2

Comment: I am going to post another question but this question came to my mind when I was thinking about the axioms of rings! I feel that people often assume that binary operations are closed under multiplication in ring definition such as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361466/should-a-ring-be-closed-under-multiplication.
But i feel like this is vacuous... so I was thinking when multiplication is not closed

Comment: @AmejiB. That was exactly what I was going to put, but you beat me to it (2 it?).

Comment: Take ANY example of set (with at least two members) that IS closed, choose two members $a$ and $b$, then REMOVE $ab$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the set of negative integers, this set has the property that if you multiply any two negative integers you will never get another negative integer.

Answer (score 1):

@Rowing0914 gave a nice example where multiplication acts to produce a different type of object.

Consider the set of all prime numbers $p_i$. By definition, none of these share any common factors.